# Angular 9 Material expandable row in table not hides

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-material

I tried to play in my first Angular app with this [example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/nvvrnvxqvord?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts) as a newbie and it works partially: before I click on a row the expandable row shows as empty row, after click it shows as expected. So I can't figure why expanding directly is not happening. Am I missing something of imports? I've got frustrated because my local app just copied from the example.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me in Google Chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Nikhil it doesn't work in my local project copied from the example. Example itself works fine for me too

Comment: The hiding and showing of rows are handled using css. `example-detail-row` is the element whose style is set to `height: 0;`. So you might have missed a css. The css also changes slightly in case you use `mat-cell` instead `td mat-cell`. If you can share your code it will be easier to help you out.

Comment: @Ani css copied as well. I compared all the stuff before asking and it's same so that is why I didn't share the code

Comment: @anatol Have you tried creating a new project in stackbliltz and then putting the files as it is from your local machine (not from example) and check whether its working or not?

Comment: @Ani I didn't. My project actually is Asp.Net Core + angular so I think dotnet stuff may impact on this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

if You in You app.module.ts this
 import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
I recommend learn this article https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples
I have tried and it works for me.

Comment: this one exists